# Changing the inner html with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this divs in my html

```
<img src="images/cocina1.jpg" name = "main_img" alt="alternate_text" height="250" width="150" />
<div class="imgbox" id="thumbnail_1"> <a href="#" onclick="changeTo1()"><img src="images/cocina1.jpg" alt="alternate_text" height="250" width="150" /> </a> <br />
<p>Medico1</p>
</div>
```

and the following JS

```
function changeTo1(){

    var newP = "some Paragraph"
    document.getElementById('id_descripcion_txt').innerHTML = newP;

    document.main_pic.src = "images/medico1.jpg"

    document.getElementById('thumbnail_1').innerHTML = " <a href=\"medicos/medico0.html\"><img src=\"images/cocina0.jpg\" alt=\"alternate_text\" height=%22250%22 width=\"150\" /> </a> <br /> <p>Medico0</p> "


}
```

Now, after clicking on the image that calls changeTo1(), the first part of the JS works: the 'id_descripcion_txt' does changes its innerHTML to "some Paragraph", but the other 2 statements, of changing main_pic src and the "thumbnail_1" innerHTML to something else don't work.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: main_img should be replaced with main_pic, typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> changing main_pic src and the "thumbnail_1" innerHTML to something
>   else don't work.

On making the changes,

> document.main_img.src = "images/medico1.jpg";

and

`height=\"350\"` instead of  height=%22250%22

it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably failing on the image change.  I think you want this HTML (note marked change):

```
<img src="images/cocina1.jpg" id="main_img" alt="alternate_text" height="250" width="150" />
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And this JS:

```
document.getElementById("main_img").src = ...
```

Also, you had different terms for the image ('main_pic' in one, and 'main_img' in the other).

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting a javascript error?  Unless there's a typo in your posted code,

```
document.main_pic
```

does not exist.  Try

```
document.main_img.src = "images/medico1.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the one of your image through java script, then use this code, here in this example  i have a banner and a text, when i click on the button then banner and text both changed.

```
             <html>
             <head>
             <script type="text/javascript">

                 function changeImgandText()
                  {

                  if(document.getElementById('banner'))
                  banner.innerHTML = '<img src="img1.jpg"width="100%" height=220>';
                  demo.innerHTML="Pir you are great !";
                   }
              </script>

               <p id='banner'><img src="img2.jpg" width="100%" height=220> </p>
               <b id='demo'>dude</b> </br>
              <input type='button' onclick='changeImgandText()' value='Change Text'/>

             </head>                    
             </html>
```